# pandas: groupby with conditional formula and unique values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
  
country = ['US', 'US', 'US', 'UK', 'UK', 'Canada', 'Canada', "Mexico"]
feature =  [2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1]
ID = [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1]  

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(country,feature, ID)),
               columns =['country', 'feature', 'ID'])
```

which is

```
   country  feature ID
0   US        2     1
1   US        2     2
2   US        2     1
3   UK        1     3
4   UK        1     4
5   Canada    2     1
6   Canada    2     2
7   Mexico    1     1
```

Given the above dataframe I want to perform `groupby` on `country`. I want to create a value `count` for each `country` with the following rule: If `feature ==2`, `count = number of unique entries under ID for that country`. If `feature !=2`, `count = number of total entries for that country`. So, the resulting new dataframe will look like this:

```
  country   count
0   US        2
1   UK        2
2   Canada    2
3   Mexico    1
```

Comment: Why is Canada 1 ?

Comment: what if some countries have a mix of `feature == 2` and `feature != 2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a simple condition within `groupby`

```
out = df.groupby('country').\
           apply(lambda x :x['ID'].nunique() if x['feature'].eq(2).all() else len(x))
Out[649]: 
country
Canada    2
Mexico    1
UK        2
US        2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

Count for `Canada` should be 2 in the expected output.

You can group the dataframe by `country`, then apply a function to get either unique count, or just the count based on the value of `feature`, then call to_frame, to create frame out of it.

```py
(df.groupby('country', sort=False)
.apply(lambda x:pd.Series.nunique(x['ID']) 
                    if x['feature'].eq(2).any() 
                    else pd.Series.count(x['ID'])).to_frame('count')
 )

         count
country       
US           2
UK           2
Canada       2
Mexico       1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two `groupby` operations, which is actually *faster* than a single `groupby` containing a `lambda` to test `feature`. Also, to solve the case where some countries may accidentally have a mix of `feature == 2` and `feature != 2`, we'll take the max:

```py
a = df.groupby(['country', 'ID']).size().groupby('country').size()
b = df.groupby('country').agg({'feature': max, 'ID': 'size'})
out = b['ID'].where(b['feature'] != 2, a).to_frame('count')

>>> out
         count
country       
Canada       2
Mexico       1
UK           2
US           2
```

**Speed comparison**

```py
# 1. setup
n = 100_000
ci = np.random.randint(0, 80, n)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'country': [f'c_{i}' for i in ci],
    'feature': [(i % 2) + 1 for i in ci],
    'ID': np.random.randint(0, 60, n),
})
```

```py
# test
%timeit ours(df)
# 17.5 ms ± 153 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit with_lambda(df)
# 34.7 ms ± 49.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming for each country, there is only a single value of `feature`, you can use [`.nunique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) to get the unique count for `feature==2` and use [`.size()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) to get the total entries for `feature==1`.  Then, combine the results and sort by country:

```
df_eq = df.loc[df['feature'] == 2].groupby('country')['ID'].nunique().reset_index(name='count')
df_ne = df.loc[df['feature'] != 2].groupby('country')['ID'].size().reset_index(name='count')

df_out = df_eq.append(df_ne).sort_values('country').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result:

```
print(df_out)

  country  count
0  Canada      2
1  Mexico      1
2      UK      2
3      US      2
```